# Appstore submission "Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID ........"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm facing this issue upon Appstore submission "This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID ........"?

Please some help!

---

I solved this issue. 
Historically, my iOS app has been published on a first "iTunes Connect" account, then re-published and updated on a second "iTunes Connect" account.

Recently when I have submit the application signed with the first account with the second account, I get the following error "This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID ........" during the upload.

I solved this issue by signing the application with the second account and the application uses a "Wildcard" provisioning profile (bundle identifier = "*", AppID = XXXXXXXXX.*)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have created an app with a provisioning profile that was not created for the account you're using to upload the app with tot the Appstore.

This could mean that

1. you are using an incorrect profile or that
2. the profile has since been removed for the provisioning portal, and you will need a new one to send in the app.

---

Also I've seen that at the current moment the developer site is down, and this could mean that this might be related to your problem. You will just have to wait to see.

Comment: If your second point is true, can you explaine me why the server could returns that error instead an error related to the site-down?

Comment: You will have to ask Apple about that.

Comment: Ah ok, because for me it doesn't make sense!

Comment: Anyway +1 because i think the problem is in your first point.

Answer (score 1):

I think the provisioning profile you used to make the archive does not matched associated developer profile id of your apps or you may be archived it using developer profile.